# Who or what are the being(s) that are forbidding dreamwalking into dead bodies?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, Doctor Strange dreamwalks into Defender Strange's corpse in Earth-616. After Strange portals to a location near Wundagore Mountain, the "Souls of the Damned" appear and attack him in two different universes (the corpse he is dreamwalking into in Earth-616 and his own body in Sinister Strange's universe), to stop his dreamwalking into a corpse. Related dialogue:

> **Souls of the Damned:** Stephen Strange…
> Possessing a dead body is forbidden. Forbidden.
> Trespasser! Trespasser!
> Cease your dreamwalk, or face the eternal consequences.

**Forbidden by who?** Who or what are these (apparently multiversal) being(s) that are forbidding possessing or dreamwalking into dead bodies, and will make someone that does so "face the eternal consequences"? What are "the eternal consequences"? **Do these being(s) have a parallel to, or are based on character(s) from the comics?**

Comment: For all we know, just that one soul of the damned. With the consequences being that they and their damned soul buddies will bug you forever about it. Either that or Mephisto. Probably Mephisto. It’s always Mephisto.

Comment: Any answer to this question is probably going to be speculation or comics based.

Comment: @PeterNielsen I don't mind comics-based answers. In fact, I would like to know if there's a counterpart in the comics.

Comment: Then you're in the right place!!

Comment: Who says it's not a committee doing the forbidding? Or the results of a referendum?

Comment: @Lexible Question revised to account for the possibility of multiple beings

Answer (score 10):

I have a feeling it has to do with one of two beings. There are only two beings in the comics that I think can set the rules for the entire multiverse. I think it has something to do with the Living Tribunal.

If you slow it down when they are going through the multiverse, you can see the Living Tribunal's three heads. He has the task of overseeing and maintaining the balance in all the universes and there is only one of him for the entire multiverse and beings like Eternity that are the literal embodiment of the universe answer directly to him.

I think that Doctor Strange's dreamwalking into the dead variant hinders the Living Tribunal's ability to maintain the balance in all the universes. Even Clea revealed in the post credits scene that this caused an incursion (possibly in her universe). This was after he dreamwalked into a dead variant.

There is also The One Above All, the one that is the most powerful in Marvel and considered to be the god of the multiverse. But since how we haven't heard about him in the MCU yet and we did see the Living Tribunal in *Doctor Strange 2*, I would have to say it is the Living Tribunal that forbids dreamwalking into dead bodies, especially since how Doctor Strange did it from another universe.

[image: This is a screenshot of the Living Tribunal when Doctor Strange and America are traveling through the multiverse, it is kind of hard to notice him if you don't slow the movie down around this part of it.]

Comment: +1 Speculative, but fun and well informed answer

Comment: It would be odd if he cared enough about dreamwalking corpses to send damned souls after the user, but was perfectly fine with everything else going on destroying multiple universes.

Answer (score 6):

**The Darkhold Redeemers**

Since you mentioned that answers from the comics is fine too, I tried to find if someone ever governed the usage of the Darkhold since that would basically answer your question as dreamwalking is a spell inside the darkhold and -

on the **official Marvel website** for the [Darkhold Redeemers](https://www.marvel.com/teams-and-groups/darkhold-redeemers) it reads -

> Sam, Louise, and Vicki are the Darkhold Redeemers **who dedicate themselves to saving the world from the Darkhold,** an arcane evil and the greatest known compilation of black magic bound in a book. Together, the trio adds to their ranks and with supernatural allies at their side, and prevents the Darkhold’s vast number of spells from unleashing hell on Earth.

A Little history -

> Churchmen eventually obtain the Darkhold scrolls and send them to the Vatican for safekeeping. Young monk Paolo Montesi, curator of St. Gabriel’s Library (containing dangerous occult objects), studies the scrolls, learning of the Malachy Prophecy—predicting the Papal succession until the end of time—and other dark secrets. Though tempted and tainted by the reading, Montesi’s extreme faith keeps him from using the book. **Pope Eugene III tasks Montesi’s bloodline with watching over the scrolls, granting special dispensation to marry to continue the line; the Darkhold’s magic thus extended the Montesis’ life spans.**
>
> The pope instructs Paolo to bind the scrolls into what they call the Book of Sins. Fearing the Church would learn of the book’s vampire eradication spell, in 1190, Varnae leads a vampire host in attacking Rome. Montesi leads a successful counterattack, but Varnae ultimately slays him via deceit; as this occurred, Montesi’s wife dies giving birth to his son, Giacomo, who succeeds Paolo as the Darkhold’s watchman.
>
> **Over the years, the family protects humanity from those who would seek to use the Darkhold.** In modern times, the priest Vittorio Montesi inherits the family mission. Though sterile, Vittorio makes a deal with the demonic being Chthon and casts a spell from the Darkhold. As such, Vittorio has a daughter named Victoria, whose true parentage is Chthon.

The complete history of the formation the Darkhold Redeemers is [here](https://www.marvel.com/teams-and-groups/darkhold-redeemers), but I have added only the points necessary for the answer.

No such "Darkhold Redeemers currently exist in the MCU as per my knowledge and neither is the employer of the souls of the damned known in the MCU. But the only group of people I could find that Governed the usage of the Darkhold is the darkhold redeemers.